# Timing accuracy in Python using WXPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making a simple mp3 player that plays multiple mp3's at a time.  It acts like it is mixing.  Timing is critical to ensure a pleasant user experience, otherwise it just sounds like two cats trying to solve the mid east crisis.  I need accuracy down to 10ms, and probably will need 1ms accuracy if it doesn't work out.

Currently, I'm using wxpython and I find the timing functions very poor (but great for audio playback).

```
import wx
import wx.media

class MediaPanel(wx.Panel):
    INTERVAL = 10

    def tick(self, event):
        self.totalMS += self.INTERVAL

        if mixstart == self.totalMS:
            # play the song

        elif mixend == self.totalMS:
            # stop the song

        else 
            pass
```

---

So here's my issue:  I find that the timing is inconsistent.  I can have the same songs loaded up in a playlist ready to mix, and it will mix in at what seems like random times.  I'm still new to programming in general, and from what I can tell, it's the timing function that is not accurate.  For debugging purposes, I will print out a timestamp to let me know where I am in the functions.  For some reason, the timer will just stop randomly, then start up again.

Question:  Is there a better way to do this?  Or is wx just broken for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can mix mp3 playbacks reliably in any GUI library. It is not meant to synchronize sound and if you just call two functions playing mp3s I believe there is not way to control the timing.

Easiest what comes to mind is to mix the two tracks first and then play (like in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629873/how-do-i-mix-audio-files-using-python)). Is that not good enough?