# How to add two speech_recognition.AudioData objects - python speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I would like to connect two recordings before using .recognize_google()
I was googling for some time but I didn't find anything about adding these type of objects together.

How can I do that ?

```
import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
    
with mic as source:
    audio = r.record(source=source, duration=2)
    audio +=  # different r.record ( speech_recognition.AudioData )
try:
    result = r.recognize_google(audio, language=pkl[0][1])   
except Exception as ex:
        result = str(ex)
```

> audio += audio

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'AudioData' and 'AudioData'

Comment: Check out this question, it may be able to solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499350/combine-audio-files-in-python

Comment: so, why are you concatenating the audio? Whynot  just concatenate the transcription?

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet?

Comment: Thanks @DylanKirby your pointer works in my case

Comment: With @DylanKirby 's approach above, you still need to convert the stitched AudioFile into AudioData. Here is complete code in my use case https://github.com/sameermahajan/speech_recognition/blob/main/recognize_a_marathi_number.py

Answer (score 0):

Putting it all together here is the solution for your problem:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
    
with mic as source:
    audio1 = r.record(source=source, duration=2)
    audio2 = r.record(source=source, duration=2)# 2nd recording
    with open("file1.wav", "wb") as f:
        f.write(audio1.get_wav_data())
    with open("file2.wav", "wb") as f:
        f.write(audio2.get_wav_data())

# stitch together the two wav files
import wave

infiles = ["file1.wav", "file2.wav"]
outfile = "check.wav"

data= []
for infile in infiles:
    w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
    data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
    w.close()

output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
output.setparams(data[0][0])
output.writeframes(data[0][1])
output.writeframes(data[1][1])
output.close()

# read the saved stitched .wav file with both the recordings
check = sr.AudioFile("check.wav")
with check as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

# Recognize the audio
try:
    result = r.recognize_google(audio, language=pkl[0][1])   
except Exception as ex:
    result = str(ex)
```

Hope it is not too late :) Or I guess better late than never :)